# Return the smallest value from a list, in which only certain values are eligeble - excel

Tags: arrays, excel, list, indexing, lookup

I am having some troubles formulating my problem but I hope you understand!

I have a table of firms building production plants in foreign countries in certain years. (Columns A to C).

In a seperate table i have so-called cross-national distance measures (based on the difference in gdp of the countries). (Columns G to M). Note that the distances change per year.

A simplified version of the excel would look like this:
https://new.wu.ac.at/fileadmin/wu/d/i/iib/photo/stack.JPG

What I want is a formula for the manually entered results in column D. It shall give me a result which is the following:

- It shall look in which countries the specific company has previously (years before) built plants
- It shall find the smallest cross-national distance from the current country to any of the countries previously entered
- The value should be for the year of the current plant-construction

Let me illustrate my request with the example result i would want in cell D8:

- The formula would have to find a list of countries that were previously entered in this case Turkey and Bulgaria
- It would then have to into the second table and give me the minimum of the distances from Kosovo but only to Turkey and Bulgaria
- This would have to be done in the rows for 2008 (current year)

I really hope you guys can help me, i figured out a way to find a minimum in a list and i can do it for certain years as well but the issue i am having that excel first needs to find the previously entered countries, memorize them in some kind of array and then use only these countries to consider the minimum distance.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this "array formula" for `D2` copied down

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,B$2:B$11,"<"&B2,C$2:C$11,"<>"&C2,C$2:C$11,I$1:M$1)*(G$2:G$31=B2)*(H$2:H$31=C2),I$2:M$31),1),"N/A")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That checks three conditions for your larger table - that the header row matches a qualifying country (using `COUNTIFS` function based on criteria in the small table), that column `G` matches the current year and column `H` matches the current country.

If all those criteria are satisfied then the relevant values in the table are returned, and `SMALL` finds the smallest. If there's an error (because there are no qualifying values) then `N/A` is returned

In `Excel 2010` or later versions you can use `AGGREGATE` function instead of `SMALL` - this is useful because it doesn't require "array entry"

`=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,I$2:M$31/(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,B$2:B$11,"<"&B2,C$2:C$11,"<>"&C2,C$2:C$11,I$1:M$1)>0)/(G$2:G$31=B2)/(H$2:H$31=C2),1),"N/A")`

Comment: dear barry, thank you very impressive thinking and exactly what i asked for!
If you allow one small follow-up though:
Your formula returns the smallest value of the matrix as i asked. In reality however a country is of course the closest when its value is close to zero. 

so basically what i would need adjusted if possible:
-find the smallest absolute value in the matrix (closest to zero)
-BUT return this value with the correct sign

:/ I am sorry to bother you more with this!

Comment: OK, I only just saw your comments here - it's my bed time now, I'll get back to this tomorrow....